# Jquery UI Draggable with Flash objects

Tags: jquery, draggable

How do i make a flash object draggable. Below is a youtube embed code. I'm trying to make the player draggable. Doing a .draggable on the tag object doesn't seem to work. Any ideas.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/qgnfcCZ_yew?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/qgnfcCZ_yew?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("object").draggable();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your embed code in a div
See working code: http://jsfiddle.net/CTKhK/1

```
<div id="youVid">
  ... // place embed code here
</div>

$(function(){
$("#youVid").draggable();
});
```

**Edit:**
See if this convinces you:
http://jsfiddle.net/CTKhK/2/

Comment: @Eric: Yep, you could add a padding and border to the `div` to make it more clear that it's draggable.

Comment: I'm aware of this. But it's not the proper solution. The user should be able to click on the player itself and move it around instead of having to guess where to drag from. Padding or margin will not help in this case.

Comment: @alex: Then how would the user be able to click to play the video?

Comment: Exactly the point. I've seen this done, can't remember were. now that i came to work on something that deals with dragging players, i'm finding this a challange. I'm thinking we can perhaps make drag available (player buttons unavailable) when dragging, since drag is not considered a click. Then if we click on the player, we would take out the drag shield and make the player active again. I don't know what the proper solution is or if anyone worked on something like this before.

Comment: @alex well you can solve your problem, let's say creating a div overlaying the embed code with the height being a smaller to leave the controls un-overlayed, and then apply draggable() to the overlay. Then you'll need to code some js to match the coordinates of the overlay to the "youDiv".  It's a bit hackish, but otherwise the users won't be able to control the video playback.

Comment: @Eric: I've been trying something like this but can't quite get it to work in Firefox.  I still think in this case its better to give the flash object a surrounding style to let them know its draggable.

Comment: @Andrew I agree with you, even if the drag is important e.g. droppable stuff, it won't be intuitive for the user the drag region or worse he can get pissed when he find out that he can't play it by clicking the video region.  The more intuitive design is to add a title bar like Windows. The other option is to have the user press some key, while down he can drag it (like linux alt drag).